# Are there $n$ groups of order $n$ for some $n>1$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Given a positive integer $n$, let $N(n)$ denote the number of groups of order $n$, up to isomorphism.

> **Question:** Does $N(n)=n$ hold for some $n>1$?

I checked the OEIS-sequence https://oeis.org/A000001 as well as the squarefree numbers in the range $[2,10^6]$ and found no example. Since we have many $n$ with $N(n)<n$ and some $n$ with $N(n) \gg n$, I see no reason why $N(n)=n$ should be impossible for $n>1$.

Comment: I asked this question also on math-stack-exchange.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547948/are-there-n-groups-of-order-n-for-some-n1

Comment: There are no square-free examples, because $N(n) \leq \phi(n)$, for square-free $n > 1$.

Comment: Note, though, that $N(2^k)$ grows *much* faster than $2^k$ (something like $2^{2k^3/27}$ if I remember right).  Likewise for $N(p^k)$ for any fixed prime $p$ (when $N(p^k)$ grows like $p^{2k^3/27}$).

Comment: Also: wow, I didn't know (or didn't remember) that this was the very first
OEIS sequence; what I expected would be the first is either #12 or #27.
(Question edited only to fix spelling and change ">>" to "\gg" in the TeX.)

Comment: @Stefan Kohl: Don't give more than 40 upvotes reason to trust in the readabilty of the question ?

Answer (score 26):

A "near-miss" is $N(19328) = 19324$, while the only $n \leq 2000$
such that $|N(n)-n| \leq 25$ are $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$,
$9$, $10$, $11$, $12$, $13$, $14$, $15$, $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$, $20$,
$21$, $22$, $23$, $24$, $25$, $26$, $27$, $28$, $32$, $36$, $48$, and $72$.