# Finite groups of order $n$ having exactly $n$ subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Is it known a characterization of finite groups of order $n$ having exactly $n$ subgroups?

A supplementary question: are there abelian groups other than the trivial group and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with this property?

Comment: Any particular reason you want these two numbers to be the same?

Comment: Yes! I found only few finite groups with this property: the trivial group, $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $S_3$, ... and so on.

Comment: Reminds me of this recent question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224636/are-there-n-groups-of-order-n-for-some-n1. Remeber: two is a coincidence; it takes three to make a trend.

Comment: Thanks! By looking to http://oeis.org/A018216, I found yet another example: a group of order 28.

Comment: A dihedral group $D_{2n}$ has $\tau(n)+\sigma(n)$ subgroups. Finding those numbers $n$ satisfying the equation $\tau(n)+\sigma(n)=2n$ is itself a difficult problem. The values of $n\leq 10^7$ for which the above identity holds are $1$, $3$, $14$, $52$, $130$, $184$, $656$, $8648$, $12008$, $34688$ and $2118656$ among which $14$, $52$, $130$, $184$, $656$, $34688$ and $2118656$ are of the form $2^kp$ for some odd prime $p$.

Comment: A better question, in my opinion, is that whether there are infinitely many of such groups?

Comment: @M.FarrokhiD.G., 130 is not of the form $2^kp$, $p$ prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Yes, of course!

Comment: Numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n) + \tau(n) = 2n$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A083874 up to the 24th such $n$, which is 91707741184.

Comment: $C_4\times C_2$ is such a group. It seems $1$, $C_2$ and $C_4\times C_2$ are the only abelian groups with the mentioned property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are finite groups of order $n$ having exactly $n$ subgroups
for $n = 1$, $2$, $6$, $8$, $28$, $36$, $40$, $40$, $48$, $54$, $72$,
$\dots$, and this list is exhaustive for $n < 96$.
The structures of the groups of order $< 96$ which satisfy the condition 
are as follows:

- $1$,
- ${\rm C}_2$,
- ${\rm S}_3$,
- ${\rm C}_4 \times {\rm C}_2$,
- ${\rm D}_{28}$,
- ${\rm C}_6 \times {\rm S}_3$,
- $({\rm C}_{10} \times {\rm C}_2) \rtimes {\rm C}_2$,
- ${\rm C}_2 \times ({\rm C}_5 \rtimes {\rm C}_4)$,
- $({\rm C}_3 \times {\rm Q}_8) \rtimes {\rm C}_2$,
- $(({\rm C}_3^2) \rtimes {\rm C}_3) \rtimes {\rm C}_2$, and
- ${\rm C}_6 \times {\rm A}_4$.

The [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) [SmallGroups Library](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/sgl.html) Id numbers of these groups are as follows:

```
[ [ 1, 1 ], [ 2, 1 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 8, 2 ], [ 28, 3 ], [ 36, 12 ], 
  [ 40, 8 ], [ 40, 12 ], [ 48, 17 ], [ 54, 5 ], [ 72, 47 ] ]
```

The existence of a general non-trivial "characterization" of such groups
seems rather unlikely to me.